# How not to log URLs with recovery token using Matomo

Tags: matomo

We are integrating Matomo (formerly Piwik) to monitor our application visits.
We have a page for users to recover their password, the URL looks like :

```
https://example.com/pwdRecovery?token=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
```

Could you confirm that it is unsecure to log the URL containing the recovery token with Piwik ?

It is interesting to gets statistics on this page, that is why I do not want to remove my Matomo Tracking code here, how can I remove the confidential part of the URL in my Matomo's stats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matomo (formerly Piwik) handles this for you, you just need to configure the parameters' name you want to exclude.

> Login as the Super User, go to Administration > Manage Websites > Global list of Query URL parameters to exclude field.

Documented on their FAQ :

- [How do I exclude URL query parameters from the URLs tracked, and from Pages reports?](https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_81/)